# How to activate delayed jobs on Amazon EC2 ubuntu server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, delayed-job

On Heroku, I just install an addon and it's all.
On localhost, I have installed a `deamon` gem, `delayed jobs` gems and that was done. I ran an action as

```
Notifier.delay.signup(@user)
```

and the record was added to `delayed_jobs` table. Then I ran `rake:jobs:work` and all records in `delayed_jobs` table were processed.

But on EC2, the records are added to database, but there are not processed -- how to automatically process them?

**EDIT:**
I've installed these gems:

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem "daemons", "~> 1.1.9"
```

Answer (score 4):

See https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

Or 'bin/delayed_job' in rails 4

This will fire up 1 delayed job process, note that you can and may want to run this on another EC2 box if running rails and delayed job on the same box is too resource intensive